# Which order is right: "gift giving" or "giving gifts"?

Tags: grammar, word-order

Which ones are right, why, and what is this condition called?

> When it comes to
>
> 1. gift giving ***or*** giving gifts
> 2. gift wrapping ***or*** wrapping gifts
> 3. hands shaking ***or*** shaking hands
> 4. football playing ***or*** playing football
> 5. etc.

Comment: It's hard to give a useful answer without a little more detail. Did you encounter a usage that raised this question?

Comment: I was just writing an essay, and when I wanted to say "when it comes to hands shaking" I said to myself "why not shaking hands" and so it created confusion.

Comment: Ah! See below. We would say "when it comes to shaking hands" every time. But "gift giving" is an idiomatic usage.

Comment: @Ghaith Alrestom: This whole area is probably *way* more complicated than what I've covered in my answer. Note that despite what P. E. Dant says above, it's not unknown to encounter usages like *when it comes to handshaking*. And per my answer, I'd expect *that* version to fare better in the context of political rallies, business etiquette training, etc. (where "handshaking" is a more clearly-defined and relevant, well-known activity).

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom What FF says. I ought to have been more thorough and said that _in most contexts,_ (if we are not referring to someone with a tremor) we would say _when it comes to shaking hands_ rather than _when it comes to hands shaking_ or _when it comes to hand(s)shaking_ (note: without the plural _hands._)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one practical way to think of the difference between *gift giving* and *giving gifts* (when it's used after *when it comes to* as you mentioned in a comment, which is the focus of this question):

- *gift giving* = the giving of a specific kind (the giving of gifts, in this case)
- *giving gifts* = a subjectless clause turned an *-ing* phrase (or clause, check your grammar book)

Which is why the two alternatives are quite possible if we generalize the patterns to [ X Ying ] vs. [ Ying X ], but one main difference is that in [ X Ying ] (i.e., *gift giving*), Y has become a noun, while in [ Ying X ] (i.e., *giving gifts*), Y is still a verb.

Having said that, I don't think there is a hard and fast rule that can tell which alternative is preferred. In other words, we have to select them on a case by case basis. (E.g., if a political leader is giving a speech after shaking hands with several other leaders, his saying *When it comes to shaking hands, ...* would most likely mean his shaking hands with other leaders, but when a doctor says *When it comes to shaking hands,* it could very well be about a medical condition. Also note that it has to compete with *handshake*, which is a well-known word, and probably is a better choice in your example.)

There are several terms for the two patterns (because there are several English grammars). But probably the most well-known ones for the two are:

- [deverbal noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deverbal_noun) (*giving* in *gift giving*)
- [participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) (*giving* in *giving gifts*, a participial phrase (or clause))

Comment: Re: *...while in [ Ying X ] (i.e., **giving gift**), Y is still a verb*, although it parallels / reverses ***gift giving*** exactly, I assume that was a typo and that you meant to use plural ***giving gifts***. Whilst there may not be a *hard and fast rule that can tell which alternative is preferred*, I think ***verbing nouns*** is always to some extend "valid" (because it's "standard syntax"), the ***noun verbing*** form may or may not be acceptable (and it never is for, say, ***football playing***).

Answer (score 3):

The "standard, base" form is *gerund [="verbing"] + noun*, following the Subject - Verb - Object pattern of standard English.

Thus *John is giving gifts* is natural phrasing, even if it's not something that would often be said because there wouldn't be many contexts where you'd *want* to say something like that.

But *John is gift giving* (which some might prefer hyphenated) is certainly a "credible" utterance. Again, it's a bit unlikely, but reversing the sequence to *attributive noun + gerund* tends to imply the activity is more generally recognised as something people do. If it wasn't used often, people wouldn't expect the reversed form (but they might suppose if *other* people use it, it *must* be a known activity, so it can sometimes be used to "elevate" the activity and make it *seem* more widely known).

That's how it works with *giving gifts* and many others (the reversed format sounds "twee" to me for that particular one, but it certainly occurs). For *gift wrapping* things are different because *that* reversed format is usually a noun (short for *gift wrapping **paper*** or similar).

You can *shake hands* or give someone a *handshake*, but *hands shaking* would only be likely to occur as an adjectival clause ([*@Spratty awoke, [with his] hands shaking*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/99655/which-order-is-right-gift-giving-or-giving-gifts/99657#comment194526_99657)). The activity itself can be called *handshaking* or *shaking hands*, again with some reference to the point made above re *literal description of activity* versus *name of known activity*.

But I have to say *John is football playing* simply doesn't work. Quite why John can go *bird watching* or *train spotting* but not *football playing* or *television watching* is not entirely clear to me. It's idiomatic.

Comment: Twee needs quotes? Have we sunk so low?

Comment: @P. E. Dant: We may never have risen to such dizzy heights as *this* before! (I can just hear you thinking *How "droll"* - but without the scare quotes, natch! :)

Comment: The example sentence you used is not in question when I want to use those gerunds and nouns. The contexts in my mind are like "when it comes to football playing or playing football. Football playing skills/knowledge or playing football skills (though this doesn't sound fine to me). I hate gift wrappings or wrapping gifts. Hands shaking or shaking hands might be more common in some places than others. Contexts like this that create confusion to me and makes me feel that it could go both ways.

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom Idioms and idiomatic usages are the most frustrating part of learning any language, without a doubt, and the most likely to make a non-native speaker feel unsure of him or herself - even one who, like you, seems to have a decent grasp of the language. The best you can do is try to remember them, use them as you gain confidence, and watch _lots_ of bad television.

Comment: :). I do watch a lot of TV shows, the best of which that have helped me with using complex phrases and sentences are Boston Legal and The Practice. But I hate it when there isn't a grammatical or syntactic rule I could just follow. I wish I had  a mentor  who I could ask whenever I am in doubt.

Comment: @Ghaith Alrestom: I think you haven't understood the thrust of my post. The reason I gave the *John is giving gifts* example is because *that's the most basic form in English* (SVO). When we consider more complex operations such as pasting together two nouns (one of them in the form of a gerund) we still need to remember that fundamental natural sequence, which leads to the usage distinction between *gift giving* and *giving gifts*. You need to understand that before you can go extending the simplest 2-word NP and start looking at things like *John has excellent **gift giving skills***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I've woken up, hands shaking, on many a Saturday morning. I blame Strongbow and single malts.

Comment: @Spratty: You're quite right. I wasn't thinking widely enough. Edited.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I was only being frivolous; no criticism intended, I assure you. Yours is a great answer but I just couldn't help myself. It comes of being British and middle aged, I suppose :-)

Comment: @Spratty: I don't suppose mine will ever be a *great* answer, but that's how things are supposed to work on SO sites. I miss things, guys like you flag them up, and the answer gets improved for posterity. That's the *theory*, anyway!